# Were the Mitzvos given because of counting of Bnei Yisrael in Bamidbar?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, bamidbar-numbers-book-of, bamidbar-parsha, census

I was reading a Dvar Torah by a prominent Rosh Yeshiva where he stated that Chazal say that the connection between the [end of Sefer Vayikra](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.27.34?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אלה המצות אשר צוה יהוה את־משה אל־בני ישראל בהר סיני
>
> These are the commandments that the LORD gave Moses for the Israelite people on Mount Sinai.

and the beginning of [Sefer Bamidbar where Bnei Yisrael are being counted](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.1.2?lang=he&with=Torah%20Temimah%20on%20Torah&lang2=he) is that Hashem gave us the Mitzvos because we are counted. The Vort then goes on to explain why this is true with the basic idea being that its because its clear that every member of the Jewish nation is important and valuable. It's a beautiful Vort but I would like to find the source of this Chazal.

So far the best I've found is that the Yalkut Shimoni (in Bamidbar and Pinchas) connects the two by saying that we got the Torah because we were able to demonstrate that our lineage was pure. This obviously is not the Chazal that the Rav was referring to as it doesn't fit at all. Can anyone find the original source? Thanks.